# Recharts tooltip crashes only when logger removed from redux middleware

Tags: redux, recharts

This application has been working fine for a while now. My local environment works but production gets crashed when tooltip moves too quickly or over too much of the line chart.

After i updated some features it still worked normally in development. So i added logger to production and it resolved. Obviously i can't leave logger in production.

Recharts recently had an update. Could middleware be affecting it's implementation?

Answer (score -1):

I had a yarn file in my build even though i'm using npm and json-package.lock. Once deleted the issue resolved. I can't explain how the logger interacted but it was completely consistent behaviour if taken out vs in.

I imagine there is a conflict between packages of recharts and something else. Once i deleted the yarn file i think it allowed my json.lock to make sure the correct version of recharts was being used. I'm not sure how logger effected this though.